# dúvida com include php

Tags: php

Bom tenho uma função onde preciso carregar um arquivo include dentro da função. Tipo assim:

```
function Query($conexao, $query) {

   // Includes
   include "../Dados.php";

}
```

o problema e que em alguns arquivos em que eu chamo a função ela não localiza o arquivo dados. Isso ocorre pois alguns arquivos estão dentro de algumas pastas. Tem alguma forma de fazer o include buscar o arquivo dados na raiz do site? Ou seja independente de onde eu chamar a função ela vai na raiz e busca o arquivo.

Comment: Se você replica esta função em diversas páginas terá de apontar o caminho, caso sua função esteja em um único script e você simplesmente o chama podes usar as constantes predefinidas como __DIR__  que ira apontar o diretório a partir de seu script que contenha a função. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: O 'DIR' foi trocado pelo 'FILE' no PHP 5.6 se não me engano. Então a função esta em um scrip único, assim eu evito de ficar duplicando código. Eu chamo o arquivo da funcção na página que eu quero com um 'include', e depois chamo a função.

Comment: Note que eu não citei a função `dir()` de diretórios más sim a contante predefinida `__DIR__` funcional no php 7.1.*

Comment: Certo. Ta mais `__DIR__`vai me retornar o caminho onde esta o 'incluide' e preciso sempre voltar a pasta raiz

Comment: Por que não usar uma constante com o caminho absoluto do arquivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `__DIR__` das contantes [predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php)

**exemplo*:

```
function Query($conexao, $query) {

   // Includes
   include __DIR__ . "../Dados.php";

}
```

`__DIR__` ira apontar a partir do diretório aonde esta o script da função.

**edição**:

A função a seguir baseia-se a partir da raiz e não relativo ao diretório como no exemplo acima:

```
function Query($conexao, $query) {
    // includes
    include  str_replace("\\", "/", dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])."/path/or/subpath/to/Dados.php");
}
```

A função acima pode ser usada para direcionar o caminho ao arquivo `Dados.php` a partir da raiz.

Um exemplo local em Windows seria algo como isto:

```
echo str_replace("\\", "/", dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])."/path/or/subpath/to/Dados.php");

// output: C:/Server/www/path/or/subpath/to/Dados.php
```

Comment: Bom ele tenta tenta encontrar o arquivo com um link errado `/Library/WebServer/Documents/Sistema/Funcoes../../Dados.php`

Comment: Acho que saquei vou dar um up na resposta

Comment: ok fico aguardando